# flutter bad state: stream has already been listened to while video compress

Tags: flutter, dart

in my flutter app i'm using video compress package. in my ui i have the user select video and when the navigate to next page it compresses first. while it is compressing i'm displaying a dialog with the progress. so for the initial compression it works fine and displays the dialog correctly. but when i do compression second time and more it throws the `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.` error. why is this happening?

the code

```
class GalleryApi {
  static Future<MediaInfo?> videoCompress(List<File?> file) async {
    try {
      await VideoCompress.setLogLevel(0);

      return VideoCompress.compressVideo(file.last!.path,
          quality: VideoQuality.LowQuality, includeAudio: true);
    } catch (e) {
      VideoCompress.cancelCompression();
    }
  }
}
```

and in the first screen

```
  Future compressVideo() async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) => const Dialog(child: ProgressDialogWidget()),
    );

    final info = await GalleryApi.videoCompress(selectedAssets.value);

    Navigator.of(context).pop();

    final size = await selectedAssets.value.last!.lengthSync();
    final ogSize = (size / 1000000).round();

    selectedAssets.value.clear();
    selectedAssets.value.add(info!.file);

    Get.to(ImagePost(
      images: selectedAssets.value,
      isVideo: isVideo,
      ogSize: ogSize.toString(),
      blurHash: [],
    ));
  }
```

and the dialog page

```
class _ProgressDialogWidgetState extends State<ProgressDialogWidget> {
  late Subscription subscription;
  double? progress;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    subscription = VideoCompress.compressProgress$
        .subscribe((progress) => setState(() => this.progress = progress));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    VideoCompress.cancelCompression();
    subscription.unsubscribe;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final value = progress == null ? progress : progress! / 100;
    final _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SizedBox(
      height: _height * 0.2,
      width: _width,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Please wait while it's compressing...",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: _width * 0.03),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: _height * 0.02,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: value,
                    minHeight: _height * 0.015,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```